# Remove ajaxcatalog=true from magento category urls

Tags: magento, url

My catalog urls are http://domain.co.uk/category/?p=2
when I click next page url changes to
http://domain.co.uk/category/?ajaxcatalog=true&p=3

How can I remove ajaxcatalog=true from the urls. Any help please

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using any Ajax extension in magento.

Please provide magento version and extension name. So, that i will guide you for proper solution.

Comment: Thankyou so much. I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and extension ajax catalog was causing that url. Just disabled it for products toolbar in system->configuration->sw extensions->Ajax Catalog